# changing MTU in Linux or Windows has no effect

Tags: linux, windows, tcp, mtu

I'm investigating an issue with a software (client) running on widows that uploads data to a controller (server) running on linux. The software uploads `1024` bytes at a time, and waits for an application layer `ACK` (`send and wait`). However, some customers have run into some issues, when uploading files through modems, since `TCP packets` get fragmented. I'm trying to reproduce the same behavior without modems. I tried setting the `MTU` of the controller to 500 using:

```
ifconfig eth0 mtu 500 up
```

but that did not force packets to get fragmented (observed in wireshark). The same happens when I set the `MTU` in windows using

```
netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface <my_interface> mtu=500 store=persistent
```

I'm pretty sure I'm choosing the correct interfaces. Any idea why changing the MTU has no effect?

EDIT:
If I run MTU discovery on windows I get:

```
MTU path scan to 172.20.35.101, ttl=64, limit=48
# 16 processing - best MSS 1472 (estimated MTU 1500) [pPPPPpPppPpppppp]


        #1 MSS IN RANGE     1 <==  1471 ==>  1472
        #2 MSS EXCEEDED  1473 <== 14911 ==> 16384
```

However the controller's ifconfig shows an MTU of 576!

```
ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:18:CF:00:10:CC
          inet addr:172.20.35.101  Bcast:172.20.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:576  Metric:1
          RX packets:5281739 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:1
          TX packets:184845 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:378840649 (361.2 MiB)  TX bytes:19017453 (18.1 MiB)
```

Comment: I think you need to make this change on the network switch(es) rather than (or as well as) on the machines.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Actually, I think `Wireshark` will only show packets before they get fragmented by the NIC as explained here: http://packetbomb.com/how-can-the-packet-size-be-greater-than-the-mtu/